# How do I access the values in the object that was just created in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite, datatables

Controller:

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController

    def form_params
        params.permit(:form_email)
    end

    def index
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
        @users = User.all
        @form = Form.create!(form_params)
        # HOW DO I PRINT OUT WHAT THE USER PUT IN FOR form_email HERE?
        redirect_to exit_path
    end
end
```

The object is created fine, but how do I access the values? Also, how would I find all the users with the same email as form_email here?

Comment: What do you mean by "PRINT OUT"? Do you want to print the form's attributes into a log file? Or do you want to show the attributes on the next (`exit_path`) page?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the values by pull Object in `show` method:

```
def show
  @form = Form.find(params[:id])
end
```

And than show in your view:

```
<%= @form.form_email %>
```

To find same email do the following:

```
Form.where(form_email: params[:form_email])
```